# PowerBI Dax Query - To find invoice which never had success state

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have to find the count of invoices that never went to a successful state at all. I tried checking multiple sites but not able to understand and recreate the query. Kindly help me. Thanks in advance.

[image]

In the above sample invoice 14 never went to success state. So the InvoiceCount = 1 and UniqInvoice count is 2.

I want the uniqInvoice count from the above table.

Comment: what is logic for uniqInvoice count?

Comment: Invoice - Invoice Number,
UniqInvoice - Concat (Invoice+Date)



---> Firstly, I want to find which Invoice is not yet processed successfully. It will give the last 3 rows.

--->Finally, DistinctCount (UniqInvoice), gives a count of 2 because we have 14-Mar-24 twice and 14-Mar 25 once

@mkRabbani

Comment: where you wants to show the value? per row or in card visual?

Comment: Measure = Card Visual as a KPI @mkRabbani

Answer (score 1):

Create a **Custom Column** and a **Measure** as below to achieve your required output-

**Custom Column**-

```
success_check = 

var current_row_invoice = your_table_name[invoice]
var count_success = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNT(your_table_name[invoice]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[invoice] = current_row_invoice
        && your_table_name[status] = "S"
    )
)

RETURN IF(count_success>=1, 1,0)
```

**Measure**-

```
unique_count = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(your_table_name[uniqinvoice]),
    FILTER(
        your_table_name,
        your_table_name[success_check] = 0
    )
)
```

Here is the output-

[image]

Comment: Hi @mKRabbani,

     Thanks for the great effort you have taken to help me out, I will try your answer also, I just found a way to do the same, I also shared my approach.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to frame the Dax Query, Hoping it will help someone.

```
FC = CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( InvoiceTable[UniqInvoice] ),
        FILTER (
            InvoiceTable,
            NOT (
                InvoiceTable[Invoice]
                    IN SELECTCOLUMNS (
                        FILTER (
                            SUMMARIZE ( InvoiceTable, InvoiceTable[Invoice], InvoiceTable[Status] ),
                            InvoiceTable[Status] = "S"
                        ),
                        "InvoiceNo", InvoiceTable[Invoice]
                    )
            )
        )
    )
```